# Understanding the Explain plan

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-execution-plan

I have a query that is taking `10 secs` of time to run currently(about 300 lines). Now I add a where condition `table_a.column_a ='XXX'` like in the below query. The amount of time it takes to run it now has increased to `300 secs`.

When I ran the explain plan. I see that this new `where` condition has some impact, looks like a sort operation(plan result below). I did not mention sort anywhere in the sql. Why is this piece so significant?

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT * from TABLE_A,TABLE_B WHERE TABLE_A.ID = TABLE_B.SOMEID AND TABLE_A.COLUMN_A='XXX';
```

**EXPLAINPLAN RESULT:**(REMOVED THE UNNECESSARY PART)

```
| Id  | Operation                                   | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                            |                            |     1 |  2878 |   154   (2)| 00:00:02 |
--removed lines here-- 
| 124 |           BUFFER SORT                       |                            |     1 |    24 |   126   (1)| 00:00:02 |
| 125 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | TABLE_A           |     1 |    24 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*126 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN                | COLUMN_A                    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Comment: What was the previous plan? Has it changed the driving table from B to A? Are your stats up-to-date?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sort operation is in place to allow for an index scan for your where condition rather than a generally more expensive sequential scan. It could be that, in this instance, the sort plus index scan is more expensive than the sequential scan would be. You could try changing this behavior by dropping the operative index, or by using hints to dictate the access method.

Comment: How would I do these? (how do I mention the hints here?) I thought that if a column is indexed, it should work without sorting again. Does the type of index have any impact?

Comment: It is hard to say without more information about your table, index, and query. To be honest, I am shaky enough on hints that I would have to get into the Oracle documentation and invite you to do the same. I believe that dropping the index would be done through an `alter table` command.